# How To Add Custom Parameters to Identity Server LogoutRequest?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a legacy ASP.NET MVC (Owin) website using the latest OpenIdConnect library, and .NET Core 3.1 MVC Identity Server app running the latest Identity Server package.

I need to pass a custom parameter to Identity Server at logout (the use case is that I need to display a different "logout reason" message depending on how the logout was initiated on the client). So I'm intercepting the `OpenIdRequestType.Logout` notification setting a custom parameter via `n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("some_key", "SomeValue")` and I can see that the `Parameters` dictionary has the new value in it. But when the `Logout` post to my Identity Server comes in, the `LogoutRequest.Parameters` collection is empty.

```
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                    {
                        switch (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType)
                        {
                            case OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout:
                                n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("some_key", "SomeValue"); 
                                break;
    ...
```

On the Identity Server side, I'm calling

```
            var logout = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
```

and finding that `logout.Parameters` is empty.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643257/how-do-you-add-parameters-to-an-identityserver-logoutrequest-model) that suggests that the oidc-client javascript library can handle adding additional parameters that will show up in the `LogoutRequest` object so I'm guessing it's possible and I'm just missing something simple. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: can you check on HTTP level if those are being sent to IdSvr in the query string? feel free to post snapshot of network tab on browser.

Comment: also I should say, you are on right track, setting parameter on `RedirectToIdentityProvider` is doing same thing that `extraqueryparameters` does on oidc-client. Both are adding a parameter to query strings when redirecting back to IdSvr

Comment: @nahidf I checked the network tab and, in fact, the parameter is added to the `connect/endession` query string, but it seems to disappear after that - the call to the `logout` endpoint in my controller that takes a `logoutId` doesn't have the parameter in the query string, and when I `GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId)`, the `Parameters` property remains empty. 

I wonder if this is a bug in Identity Server?

Comment: Confirmed as a bug in IdentityServer 4, looks like it's slated for the 4.1 release. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4824#issuecomment-689002139